# Laravel 5.1 browser testing upgraded to Laravel Dusk

Tags: php, laravel

so i am using laravel's Example.test and i have the following code:

```
public function testBasicTest()
{
   $this->get('/')
        ->type('some query', '#search')
        ->press('Search')
        ->see('Search results for "some query"')
        ->onPage('/search-results');
}
```

However, my node watch and execute script is telling me what is on the image bellow:
[image]

But according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing, this methods are supposed to exist. Is this because i am using laravel 5.5/5.4?

Comment: If you're using 5.5, why not peruse the 5.5 docs instead of the 5.1 ones?

Comment: Hello there, the reason for that is because i am learning 5.1 features and will move up soon. However, with laravel-browser-kit-testing you can use old features. Thanks!

Comment: There's really no point in learning 5.1 features if you intend to use 5.5. The 5.5 docs will cover everything in 5.1 that's still around in 5.5.

Comment: But the tutorial i am following organized it this way https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/ and i think that the 5.1 series has unique stuff.

Comment: The majority of stuff in 5.1 will still be present in 5.5. Nothing wrong with following along with that tutorial, but there's no reason to consult the 5.1 docs while you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods were removed in laravel 5.4 in favor of browser testing with Dusk.

However, from [the 5.4 upgrade docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade):

> Laravel 5.4's testing layer has been re-written to be simpler and
>   lighter out of the box. If you would like to continue using the
>   testing layer present in Laravel 5.3, you may install the 
>   [laravel/browser-kit-testing package](https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing) into your application. This
>   package provides full compatibility with the Laravel 5.3 testing
>   layer. In fact, you can run the Laravel 5.4 testing layer side-by-side
>   with the Laravel 5.3 testing layer.

Comment: Since those methods were removed, i can't use them any longer, however the browser kit testing package doesn't recognize some methods so this is kind of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `visit` stuff (and everything else that's browser-based) appears to require Laravel Dusk in 5.5.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk#installation

Comment: I suppose the correct answer is, i cannot use  these methods anymore, i have to use dusk or laravel's browserkit testing package.